# Ruby on Rails 3 - Stylesheets and Javascripts on separate domains

Tags: javascript, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, stylesheet

I have seen many websites use a separate domain, or subdomain to serve javascript and stylesheets to speed up site load time.
How do I go about implementing the same in my Rails 3 web app?

For example I want

`<link href="/stylesheets/style.css?1304887417" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

to show as

`<link href="http://images.domain.com/stylesheets/style.css?1304887417" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

I am using this tag to show the stylesheets: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style', :media => 'screen' %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supplying an absolute URL is the most direct way.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'http://images.domain.com/stylesheets/style.css', :media => 'screen' %>
```

I recommend writing your own view helper to help with this.

Edit: Hey, I just learned something today.  Check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html  under "Using asset hosts" for info on how to set up AssetTagHelper to call a CDN, even supporting the multiple server CDN case of assets1.example.com, assets2.example.com, etc.

Comment: OK that works. Just one thing, it doesn't have the timestamp at the end. E.g. `style.css?129563483`. I would like this to still show as it is for a beta site and the CSS would be updated every day or two.

Comment: Updated my answer.  This is what you want.